# How to find a String in a variable if I have only part of that String in batch scripting

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

In windows Batch Script I have a variable.

`VarSQL="Select * from Tablex where Timetstampcol < A_XXX_ABC"`

I need to find the String from the above Select stmt with contains 
'A_XXX' and replace it with another value .

Problem is I'm unable to get the complete string  A_XXX_ABC from the above variable with just A_XXX .

Is there any way I can come to know Which is the complete string which contains A_XXX since A_XXX is the only constant subtring and other part ABC will keep on changing like A_XXX_XYZ ,A_XXX_OOO etc.

Please help me out with the code to parse and find such string and assign them in a variable .
I do know How I can replace it since its pretty basic.

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that what you want to do is not possible: the goal of batchfiles is to collect a list of commands, which can then be run "in batch" (hence the name). This can involve some basic intelligence (like an IF- or a FOR-loop), but once you want to do more intelligent processing (like string manipulation) I would advise you to search for other technologies (Python, Perl, ..., other script languages). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet searches the input string in `VarSQL` and returns the first word beginning with the value in `SearchStr` (`SearchLen` must contain the length of the search string). A word is considered each string portion delimited by any of the following characters: `*`, `<`, `>`, `(`, `)`, `=`, `,`, `;`, <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (see the `delims=` option; the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> must be specified as the last one):

```
@echo off
set "VarSQL=Select * from Tablex where Timetstampcol < A_XXX_ABC"
set "SearchStr=A_XXX"
set /A SearchLen=5

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SubStr=%VarSQL%"
:LOOP
for /F "tokens=1,* eol=  delims=*<>()=,; " %%I in ("%SubStr%") do (
    if "%%I"=="" goto :SKIP
    set "SubStr=%%I"
    if not "!SubStr:~,%SearchLen%!"=="%SearchStr%" (
        set "SubStr=%%J"
        goto :LOOP
    )
)
:SKIP
endlocal & set "SubStr=%SubStr%"
echo "%SubStr%"
```

Afterwards, to actually replace the found string with another string in `ReplaceStr`, do the following:

```
set "ReplaceStr=A_XXX_XYZ"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "VarSQL=!VarSQL:%SubStr%=%ReplaceStr%!"
endlocal & set "VarSQL=%VarSQL%"
echo "%VarSQL%"
```

...or, if you want to avoid delayed expansion:

```
set "ReplaceStr=A_XXX_XYZ"
call set "VarSQL=%%VarSQL:%SubStr%=%ReplaceStr%%%"
echo "%VarSQL%"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set VarSQL="Select * from Tablex where Timetstampcol < A_XXX_ABC and Timetstampcol > coumnEndTS"
echo Before: !VarSQL!

for /F %%a in ("!VarSQL:*A_XXX=A_XXX!") do set "VarSQL=!VarSQL:%%a=A_ZZZ_OPQ!"

echo After:  !VarSQL!
```

Output:

```
Before: "Select * from Tablex where Timetstampcol < A_XXX_ABC and Timetstampcol > coumnEndTS"
After:  "Select * from Tablex where Timetstampcol < A_ZZZ_OPQ and Timetstampcol > coumnEndTS"
```